# is there a way i can have an array of different ids that are allowed to run a command in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to have a list of IDS that are allowed to use a specific command so I can have another command that can add more ids to the list I came up with this

```
let allowed = ['allowed ID', 'allowed ID']

if(!msg.author.id === allowed ) return msg.channel.send("You're not allowed to use this command")
```

it didn't work is there a way to do this in js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let allowed = ["id", "id2", etc..];
if(!allowed.includes(msg.author.id)) return msg.channel.send("You're not allowed to use this command");
```

This uses array.includes(valueToCheck).

In your case, you say that if the id of the author (which is a number) is desame as the array.

To edit the array using a command:

If you use a command handler, you must save that array under the thing you send between the files (in most cases message, args, prefix and client) and then use array.push. **or** if you use 1 file for both commands you can just use allowed.push(id) to add an id.